# Move cursor by itself in his current position

Tags: c++, windows

I work on a program that moves the cursor itself on his current position.

I have deleted my previous question because it wasn't [Minimal and Reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

So my program work like this, I get the current cursor position using `GetCursorPos` function, and then move the cursor by using `SetCursorPos`.

My cursor is moving itself like i wanted, but the cursor position is always at the top left on the screen.

- I don't usually use `using namespace std;`,
  But in this short program no problem to use it

This is my current code, any suggestions ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    POINT p;
    BOOL bPos = GetCursorPos(&p);

    while (true) {

        int x = rand() % 10;
        int y = rand() % 10;
        bPos = SetCursorPos(x, y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are never seeding your random generator by calling `srand`. You'll get the same "random" numbers every time. Btw; do look into [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks, I fixed it, any suggestions for my main problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a couple of problems:

- Including `<iostream>` and `<vector>` is useless here.
- You save the return value of the `SetCursorPos` function, but never use it.
- You never seed the `rand` function, so it always gives the same results.

Then, the problem is that you randomize both the `x` and the `y` in a range from `0 - 9`.
Now, since the coordinate `(0; 0)` is located at the top-left corner we can see the reason you get the results that you get.

You can get your desired behaviour by updating the current position every time in your `while` loop and changing the coordinates respective to their the current position.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    srand(time(nullptr));
    POINT current_position;

    while(true){
        GetCursorPos(&current_position);

        int offset = rand() % 2;
        int x_direction = rand() % 2 == 1 ? 1 : -1;
        int y_direction = rand() % 2 == 1 ? 1 : -1;

        SetCursorPos(current_position.x + (offset * x_direction), current_position.y + (offset * y_direction));
        Sleep(10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Another thing you might want to do is look into the `<random>` library. It would simplify your code to this:

```cpp
#include <thread> // sleep_for()
#include <random>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    mt19937 engine(random_device{}());
    uniform_int_distribution<> range(-1, 1);

    POINT current_position;

    while(true){
        GetCursorPos(&current_position);
        SetCursorPos(current_position.x + range(engine), current_position.y + range(engine));

        this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: prefer using the standard way of doing things, in this case, sleeping.

Comment: I have used this variable to the cursor posistion, when I use your variable values, my cursor is just fricking out around the screen.

Comment: I want to be able to move my mouse and move the mouse 10 pixels, and not 1920 & 1080, if I use 1920 & 1080, my mouse is move 1920 pixles away from his current position.

Comment: Thanks! But it is still not what i wanted to do, let me give me a dirty example, lets take "VineMemz" malware, you can see that the mouse is moving itself exactly like i want to do *i gave this malware only for example, if you want search for vinememz in youtube.

Comment: Please look at it now.